# Posting to database doesn't work (Error/Warning: Unexpected end of JSON input)

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, database, native

I am working on a mobile app with React Native. The problem is that it seems like I am unable to insert anything into the database. I have a sign up page where a user needs to write a username and a password (and repeat that password), which was working fine a few months ago. I haven't changed anything on that particular page, but when I started adding new pages, for example the other page that doesn't work, it stopped working and gave me the warning that can be seen here:

[image]

The other page that doesn't work is where the user can post a job with title dates and such. This page is not done, but it should be done enough so that the user can post something to the database, but it gives me the error that can be seen here:

[image]

The code for the sign up page is the following (stylesheet not included):

```jsx
import React, { Component } from "react"; 
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Alert, TextInput, ImageBackground, Image, AsyncStorage, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { Button, Icon, withTheme } from 'react-native-elements';

const SIGNUP_URL = 'http://kamilla-server.000webhostapp.com/app/signUp.php';

class SignUp extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state= {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        password2: '',
    };
 }

async onSignUp() {
    const { email, password, password2 } = this.state;

    if(this.state.email != '' && this.state.password != '' && this.state.password2 != '') {
        if(password != password2) {
            Alert.alert('Password matcher ikke', 'De to indtastede passwords skal være det samme password')
        } else {
            const response = await fetch(SIGNUP_URL, {
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
            })

            const data = await response.json()


            if (data.error) {
                alert(data.error)
            } else {
                AsyncStorage.setItem('UserID', data.user.UserID)
                this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUpMessage')
            }
        }
    } else {
        Alert.alert('Tomme felter', 'Venligt indtast email og password for at kunne oprette en bruger')
    }
}

render() {
    const { email, password, password2 } = this.state;

    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ImageBackground source={require('../../images/1088.jpg')} style={styles.background} />

            <View>
                <Image source={require('../../../assets/logo.png')} style={styles.logo} />

                <TextInput
                    value={email}
                    onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
                    placeholder={'Email'}
                    placeholderTextColor='white'
                    keyboardType='email-address'
                    style={styles.input}
                />

                <TextInput
                    value={password2}
                    onChangeText={(password2) => this.setState({ password2 })}
                    placeholder={'Password'}
                    placeholderTextColor='white'
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    style={styles.input}
                />

                <TextInput
                    value={password}
                    onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
                    placeholder={'Password'}
                    placeholderTextColor='white'
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    style={styles.input}
                />

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')}>
                    <Text style={styles.underlined}>Har du allerede en konto? Login.</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <Button 
                    title="Opret Konto" 
                    buttonStyle={styles.greenButton}
                    onPress={this.onSignUp.bind(this)}
                />

            </View>

        </View>
    )
 }
}

export default SignUp;
```

The URL SIGNUP_URL links to the following code:

```php
<?php
    require_once('../db/dbcon.php');

    session_start();

    try {
        $inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE);

        $email = htmlspecialchars($input['email']);
        $password = htmlspecialchars($input['password']);

        $dbCon = dbCon($user, $pass);
        $query = $dbCon->prepare("SELECT `user`.Email FROM `user` WHERE `Email` = ?");
        $query->bindParam(1, $email);
        $query->execute();
        $getUser = $query->fetchAll();

        if(count($getUser) > 0) {
            $status = 0;

            echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Der findes allerede en bruger for den indtastede email.'));
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `user` (`UserID`, `Email`, `Password`)
                        VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)";
            $query = $dbCon->prepare($sql);
            $query->bindParam(1, $email);
            $query->bindParam(2, $password);

            $query->execute();

            $last_id = $dbCon->lastInsertId();
            $query2 = $dbCon->prepare("SELECT `UserID`
                                    FROM `user`
                                    WHERE `UserID` = '{$last_id}'");
            $query2->execute();
            $getNewUser = $query2->fetch();
            if ($query2) {
                echo json_encode(array('user' => $getNewUser));

                $_SESSION['userID'] = $getUser['UserID'];
                //$_SESSION['volunteerID'] = $getVolunteer['VolunteerID'];

            } else {
                echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Der gik noget galt. Venligst prøv igen.'));
            }
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        error_log(print_r($e->getMessage(), TRUE));
    }

?>
```

Comment: The stack trace in your images is referencing a function called `tryCallOne`, but I don't see the code for that anywhere. Can you edit your answer with that code?

Comment: If you `console.log(response)`, what does that tell you? If you use `react-native-debugger` you could easily see the requests (- and their responses) in the network tab.

Comment: @MattGrande I have never called the function `tryCallOne`. The code you see is all the code I have for this. If you need code for the other pages, I can give you the GitHub link.

Comment: @entiendoNull It gives me an "unexpected token <" error, which doesn't make sense. I have previously tried to put in `alert(await response.text())` instead of `await response.json()`, which would give me an alert box with html, and there was no errors in that.

Comment: well, I assume that `response` does not contain what you want it to be. What does the response headers say? If you try to register a user by using "Postman" or some other tool that you might have you'll surely get some more feedback. I defientely recommend `react-native-debugger` though.

Comment: Using Insomnia I get the error "Undefined index UserID", but it also echoes UserID which it should, so the error does not make any sense.

Comment: Unsure, whether it is of importance or not. But where you `INSERT` you specify the UserID as an affected column, but you don't bind any parameter to it? Does parameter count work that way in the specific lib? Don't you need to specify the right amount of params to the amount of affected columns? Is anything inserted to the databse?

Comment: I do not bind a parameter to the UserID because there is no data to bind. It is an auto increment column. This is how I've always done it and it has always worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this line:
    `$_SESSION['userID'] = $getUser['UserID'];`
The `$getUser` needed to be `$getNewUser`, since that is the name of the variable I fetch from. I must have changed it at some point without realizing, thereby creating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here but my best guess is your fetch api is receiving an error you should try modifying the `async onSignUp` function's fetch to something like:

```
  await fetch(SIGNUP_URL, {<params>})
    .then(res => {
      // Handle API Errors
      if (!res.ok) {
        console.log(res.statusText);
      }
      // Return if no errors
      return res.json();
    })
    // this is the data you want
    .then(data => data)
    // it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.message)
    });
```

you can try the above approach to see if you are getting an error in the response!
Hope this helps!!

Comment: It gives me the error "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined".

Comment: seems like you are getting the error in the first then that means the response.ok flag is not true, so your api is not giving you the correct response or maybe your API needs something else. I would suggest testing the API once via an external app like **postman**

Comment: Using Insomnia I get the error "Undefined index UserID", but it also echoes UserID which it should, so the error does not make any sense.